# What is the difference between Salat and Salah?

Tags: salat, arabic

That's it. Not much more detail in the question.

If the answer could include usage  in a sentence, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They're exactly the same word.  In Arabic, the word صلاة‎ (salah/salat) ends with what is known as a *[taa marbutah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taw#T.C4.81.CA.BC_marb.C5.AB.E1.B9.ADah)*, which can be pronounced either as "t" (if it's in the middle of a sentence) or an "h" (if it's at the end of a sentence).

Comment: If I were saying it in English, would `it's time for salah. is it salat time?` be correct?

Comment: @Shamoon Yes and no.  Applying Arabic grammar rules to an English sentence is just confusing, better off just sticking to whichever pronunciation you prefer.

Comment: @goldPseudo is right that "Applying Arabic grammar rules to an English sentence is just confusing" , but assume in regard to ur question which asked "it's time for salah. is it salat time", then u'd better to say it by the letter "h (salah)" , Since its main word is Salah, then in case you add some word to it you ought to say it by "t" according to Arabic. So I reckon you cannot observe this grammar in English. Anyhow I think the response of dear goldPseudo is good enough to persuade you. Good luck.

Comment: To be entirely accurate: ṣalāt all on its own is not correct in Classical Arabic: you need to add a case ending (ṣalātun, ṣalātin, aṣ-ṣalātu etc.). ṣalāh is the pausal form, which you use at the end of a sentence, or at the end of an ʼāyah in the Qur’an.

Answer (score -2):

It is exactly the same, depending on the context of usage.  At the end of iqama we use "salah", and in the middle we use "salat".

Comment: Assalamu alaikum... [How do I write a good answer?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) Also plz read other answers. You might get to learn from those answers... All the best.. :)

Answer (score -3):

Basically according to my info. As much as I can remember, there wouldn't be any special difference between the mentioned words (Salah/Salat) from the aspect of meaning and their meanings almost are the same. But apparently there is a little difference from grammar aspect.